# PostgreSQL - ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type integer

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, odbc

I'm attempting to write some data to a PostgreSQL database using C# .NET via the ODBC driver `Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)}`.  Does this driver have any known data type matching issues?

I'm trying to send in a GUID and a DateTime field.  The database columns are typed as a `uuid` and a `timestamp without timezone`.  When I attempt to send either one, I get back errors.  When I send the GUID into the uuid field, I get back this error: 
`ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type integer`

For the datetime, I get the following: `ERROR: column "createdate" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type integer;`

Here is some short code that illustrates the problem.  This fails:

```
        var p = new OdbcParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@1",
            DbType = DbType.Guid, // I also tried OdbcType = OdbcType.UniqueIdentifier
            Value = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
        var sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (@1)";
        using(var conn = new OdbcConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new OdbcCommand(sql))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add(p);
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

As a sanity check, I tried it with SQL-injection and it works:

```
        var sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES ('" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + "')";
        using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new OdbcCommand(sql))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

If I involve the date time field, I get the same results, different error message.

Is the ODBC drive mismatching something?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to comments below, this appears to work.  I named the parameter "x" and used ? (question-mark) in the INSERT statement.  It appears that the parameters are positional.

```
    var p = new OdbcParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "x",
        DbType = DbType.Guid,
        Value = Guid.NewGuid()
    };
    var sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (?)";
    using(var conn = new OdbcConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var command = new OdbcCommand(sql))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add(p);
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `@1` is a correct name of DB parameter. Change it and try.
I tried out in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with PostgreSQL9.3...it does not recognize `@1` as a parameter, considers it as a integer.

I had this error there:

> ERROR: column "data" is of type uuid but expression is of type integer
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 36

Comment: Any suggestions on what I should try?  I just now tried `@x` and `:myparam`.  For @x, it says that the x is not a column name and for :myparam it doesn't like the colon.

Comment: Can you try $x or $1 ? I was just googling out...seems a bit confusing :P

Comment: OK question-mark ? works in the INSERT statement and random words like x work in the Parameter object.  However, since it appears to be positional anyway, the name doesn't matter.